# Make a menu with a fixed position disappear on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, optimization, menu, css-position, fixed

I want a small menu inside a < p > which I've given a fixed position (right) to disappear on mobile devices. The menu currently appear on top of photos on mobile devices which doesn't look very nice. I've been testing with my android (samsung) and the android browser.

This is the code:

```
p.pos_fixed
{
position:fixed;
top: 70%;
left: 93%;
margin-left: 0px;
}
```

and after < body > :

```
<p class="pos_fixed">
 <a href="http://www.bjarteedvardsen.com/brollop" />Portfolio</a> «
 <br/><a href="http://www.bjarteedvardsen.com/brollop/blogg" />Blogg</a> «
 <br/><a href="http://www.bjarteedvardsen.com/brollop/info" />Info</a> «
 <br/><a href="http://www.bjarteedvardsen.com/brollop/kontakta" />Kontakta</a> «
 <br/><a href="http://www.bjarteedvardsen.com/brollop/bjarte" />Bjarte</a> «
 <br/><a href="http://www.facebook.com/bjarte.edvardsen" target="_blank" />Facebook</a> «
</p>
```

The website is [www.bjarteedvardsen.com/brollop](http://www.bjarteedvardsen.com/brollop).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a z-index for example:

```
p.pos_fixed
{
  position:fixed;
  top: 70%;
  left: 93%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  z-index:999;
}
```

the z-index tells the browser what is on top of what, the higher the number, the higher up top. Default is 0, negative values can be used but may not be practical for you.